# Downloading m3u8 videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-streaming, youtube-dl, file-download

I am trying to download video from a `.m3u8` livestream video format.

How can I download m3u8 videos using software on my personal computer such as `ffmpeg`, `youtube-dl`, `VLC`, etc?

> M3U is a computer file format for a multimedia playlist. One common use of the M3U file format is creating a single-entry playlist file pointing to a stream on the Internet. The created file provides easy access to that stream and is often used in downloads from a website, for emailing, and for listening to Internet radio.
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71904/discussion-on-question-by-farouk-downloading-m3u8-videos).

Comment: I've made a cross platform desktop application for this purpose. https://github.com/dotnettools/SharpGrabber

Comment: this question is being discussed on Meta: https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14603/why-is-this-question-about-downloading-an-m3u8-video-file-off-topic

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Get [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), then you can download your video with this command:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls,crypto -i "http://s6.vidshare.tv/hls/pdommq4tlsm4f4kmledsh5d5fcn27i35msjxqw62lfflut5bgaqhb5kirb5q/index-v1-a1.m3u8" -c copy video.mp4
```

But it may be easier to use [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/). If it supports the website that contains the video you can type e.g.:

```
youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/...
```

This works not just for YouTube but also many other video sites.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67395/discussion-on-answer-by-spiderpig-downloading-m3u8-videos).

Comment: Thanks! Works for me on linux

Comment: youtube-dl now also supports m3u8 link now. (although it just uses ffmpeg in the backend)

Comment: @SwiftMango How do you input an m3u8 file into youtube-dl? What is the command?